# Beamer: header and footline not showing up

Tags: beamer

I'm using beamer to create a simple presentation. I use standard themes:

```
\documentclass{beamer} % beamer
\usepackage{pgfpages} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
```

However, I don't see the header and footline. I only have the slide title and navigation bar. 
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. My frames were created like:

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
```

By removing [plain], I get the expected result.

Comment: Nice that you could find the solution, but I would like to point that this information was not shown in your question, so nobody could help you.